# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with glTexImage2D in GLKViewController

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

I have an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at the last line of this code (this code is fired several times per second), but I cannot figure out what is the problem:

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context];
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _backgroundTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, _outputFrame.cols, _outputFrame.rows, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, _outputFrame.data);
```

When debugging I make sure that the texture is created (the id is > 0), output frame has a valid pointer to the data and is a 4 channel matrix. I am inside the `drawRect` method of a GLKViewController. I think I should not have to bind the framebuffer as it is one of the things that are automated here. **It doesn't crash at the first frame, but a few dozens frames later.**

Can anybody spot the problem?

**UPDATE:**

It seems it's because of a race condition on `_outputFrame`, it's being updated while being read by `glTexImage2D`. I will try to lock it for read, then report back.

Comment: Would be nice if you could post your solution, so others can benefit from it should they have similar problem.

Comment: I posted it, but don't know if it can be useful to anyone, as it is very specific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was the solution indeed (see **UPDATE**), I fixed it with `NSLock`. Firstly I swapped the instance variable `_outputFrame` with a temporary one that gets updated from another thread and used the lock to update the instance variable:

```
[_frameLock lock];
_outputFrame = temp;
[_frameLock unlock];
```

Then used the lock when I wanted to read from the instance variable:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _backgroundTexture);
[_frameLock lock];
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, _outputFrame.cols, _outputFrame.rows, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, _outputFrame.data);
[_frameLock unlock];
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out some problem like this after several days.

```
1. better  avoid rendering  in multi-thread
2. better  render in GLKView with base affect, and don't manually manage framebuffer& render buffer by yourself
3. base effect render raw pixel data like this
```

My solution:

```
glTexImage2D(...);
self.baseEffect.texture2d0.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeReplace;
self.baseEffect.texture2d0.target = GLKTextureTarget2D;
self.baseEffect.texture2d0.name = texture;
self.baseEffect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;
self.baseEffect.useConstantColor = YES;
```

Comment: I edited your post for grammar and layout. Thanks for the feedback, but I don't know why you're suggesting not to use multithreading when it really depends on the case and also I am using custom shaders, not GLKBaseEffect.